# Leviton GFCI is not working

Tags: electrical, receptacle, circuit-breaker, gfci

I am helping a friend who had a circuit trip. Reset the breaker and it tripped again. Saw one of the GFCIs was tripped. They replaced with a new one but the circuit still is not working. The breaker is back on and is saying the wire is hot.

So I connected the Line wire to line, and Load to the load. The green Light is on but no power at receptacles or anything downstream.

I'm also assuming this is the beginning of the circuit because as far as I know the entire circuit is not working.

So I've read that after switching the load and lines this resolved many peoples problems. However this is not working for me. When I switch my load and lines I get a red blinking indicator.

Any ideas ?

I was told that they tried putting a regular non GFCI on but did not get any different results but I personally did not try it at the time.

Comment: Does any part of this circuit have an outside outlet that could have got wet?   Any signs of mice?

Comment: First push the test button till you hear a click. Than Push the rest button till you hear a click

Comment: How are travelers being used in this context?  What are you doing with neutrals?  What happens if you connect nothing to the LOAD terminals of the GFCI?  You know GFCIs have both a LINE hot and a LINE neutral, and that neutrals are special and not just a common like automotive wiring... right?

Answer (score 5):

Let's start with terminology. "Travelers" typically refers to 3-way/4-way switches. I think in this context you are using it to refer to "load", as in the wires going on to the next receptacle/switch/etc.

With any receptacle that has more than one cable (or set of wires), there is typically one that is coming from the source (breaker panel or another junction that is closer to the breaker panel). We'll call that **LINE**. I don't like calling it hot because it actually includes both an actual "hot" wire and a *neutral* wire. The second cable (can actually be more than two, but most common is just two cables) we'll call **LOAD**. It is a *load* with respect to a GFCI as it is controlled by the GFCI. As with LINE, LOAD includes both a hot wire and a neutral wire.

The starting point is always to work on just one cable. With power off at the breaker, disconnect all the cables from the GFCI/receptacle and spread them out so they can be checked safely. Turn the breaker back on. Use a non-contact voltage tester to check and you should find just one *hot* wire. That wire should be black (unless in conduit) and is the hot wire for LINE. There should be a white wire paired with it, which is the neutral wire for LINE.

Turn power off. Connect these two wires to an ordinary (not GFCI) receptacle. Turn power on. Check for power with a 3-light tester and/or a multimeter. You should have ~120V between hot and neutral, ~120V between hot and ground, 0V between neutral and ground. If you don't, stop here and ask for help. Check with a device (light, radio, fan, etc.) and make sure it works. If it doesn't work, stop here and ask for help.

Turn power off. Replace the receptacle with a GFCI/receptacle. Make sure hot and neutral are connected to the "line" side. Usually (but not guaranteed) the top set of screws. Turn power on. Check power as with a regular receptacle. If you get nothing at all, there may be a GFCI RESET required before first use. If you can't get it to work, stop here and ask for help. If it does work, make sure TEST and RESET work before continuing.

Turn power off. Attach the second cable to the "load" side. Usually the bottom set of screws. Turn power on. If the GFCI shows no power and won't reset then you have a problem in the downstream receptacle(s)/lights/switches/etc. If everything works, check power at the downstream receptacles.